# Session destroyed after redirection

Tags: java, session, servlets, filter, chained

I'm facing an issue in a new application I'm working on it.
I made a new entry point (used for a non logged user) and I want to store a value in the user session (value comes from a path param).

So, my entry point like this :

```
@GET
@Path(MYPATH + "/{" + VALUE + "}")
public Response myEntryPoint(@PathParam(VALUE) String value, @Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @Context HttpServletResponse response) {
    httpServletRequest.getSession().setAttribute(URL, value);
        LOGGER.info(HttpServletRequest.getSession().getId());
        return Response.seeOther(new URI(the login system)).build();
}
```

The "login system" is another application and will perform some actions like the login of the user and then call another endpoint of my application.
My goal is to retrieve the value put on the session.
So, I wrote the following code :

```
@GET
@Path(action)
public Response action(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    LOGGER.info(request.getSession().getId());
    String value = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute(URL);
```

}

I would expected the value contained the value given on parameter on the myEntryPoint call.
But, as you can imagine, the String value is empty and if I check the session ids of the requests (myEntryPoint & action) are differents.
When the action method is called, a lot of filter chained are called.
Do you know what I did wrong?
I tried the same exercice with cookies in place of session, but without success.
Value is still empty.

Do you have any idea / suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is two different applications? They run in different VMs. How do you want they to share something? You need to send something like a JWT so the other application can retrieve information over the logged in user.

Comment: Hi, pringi, Thanks for your response.  In fact, Application A retrieve a request and call application B. Application B takes some actions and call another service of Application A. So, I'm not sure, the session has to be destroyed.

Comment: On possible solution: https://www.baeldung.com/java-json-web-tokens-jjwt.

Comment: The login flow between Application A and B works already fine. The only things I want is to allow a user to send a value on parameter (first request on application A) and allow the  second call on application A (after the login process on application B) to retrieve the same value.

Comment: ps : it is not a spring application and I don't have access to application B

Comment: You cannot use session for that ( httpServletRequest.getSession().setAttribute(URL, value);) because they are two different applications. You need to pass the parameter in your call to the login system. Something like: new URI(the login system?url=value). Unless other mechanism is used (like a distributed cache, a database or something else where you have a key that is passed in each request and you can later retrieve the respective value (like jsessionId) , you need to send in each request between apps the "session" values. Something like it is done in JWT that represents the "session".

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but what about a cookie solution in this case? I mean, if in place of put my value on the session, I put the value on a cookie, is-it better? As the cookie will be created and read on the application A, it should work, no?